# SSRS Reports Export to PDF and append other documents

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am having a requirement where in I am creating some sort of packages. There could be one or two SSRS reports (RDLs per say) part of the package and then there could be some other pdf files included in that.

So in turn the requirement is to merge one or more RDL and one or more pdf files together and make it a single pdf and allow the user to download it.

I am not sure if this can be achieved as it is asked in SSRS itself. My question is specifically if this kind of things can be achieved in SSRS.

I have the other approach where in I export the reports store them some where, pick the couple of PDF files in question and store them in the same folder and then zip it and go from there but thats something is not really wanted.

Could you help me on this or guide me to some resources/approaches?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to play around a bit but one way to make it work is to place all your reports as sub reports into your main report.. so when you run the main report.. it runs all the other sub reports.. when you export this, it should export as one document. What is not clear here is,  if they have different parameters etc for different reports (sub reports) or if they have any parameters at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I am certainly thinking in that direction and I think it is possible to do. I will have same set of parameters for all reports, so thats not a problem. What I am checking here is if I can embed one or more pdf files in the reports. These pdfs are some static files. Say these are contract documents uploaded to the cloud. While generating the report, requirement is to add the documents/pdfs into the report. How will this be possible?

Comment: I don't think you can directly do this.  But one work around is to have your pdf files as images and then embed these images.  End result will be the same right